# Domain configuration W WW or WWWW

Tags: apache, dns, cpanel

Hi have multiple domain for one web application hosted on tomcat. My server is managed with web host manager and cPanel. This domains are configured ok and shows web applications if you type domain with or without www

Now I want to do this configuration. If somebody type w.domain.com, ww.domain.com or wwww.domain.com go to web application too.

I don't know where I must do this configuration. Must I add CNAME register on DNS with 1,2 and 4 W? Or some configuration on apache?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Both. The CNAME is just a reference to the record for the IP that the dns system will resolve for you. The Apache server still sees "w" "ww" or "wwww" coming in.

However, it is quite likely that the Apache is configured to accept *.domain.com which means you do not need to change anything.